# Returning values with python

Tags: python, list

current result returns

```
 [['jackson', ['21', '22'], ['20','24']], ['barkley', ['30', '32'], ['33', '34']]]
```

I want to separate the values so that

```
   a = jackson, barkley
   b = (jackson, 21), (jackson, 22), (jackson, 23), (jackson 24), (barkley, 30)..etc
```

What would be the best way? Thanks.

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mgilson Yes. Sorry about the typo..

Comment: Hint: use for loops.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = [['jackson', ['21', '22'], ['20','24']], ['barkley', ['30', '32'], ['33', '34']]]
>>> [(i[0],z) for i in d for j in i[1:] for z in j]
[('jackson', '21'), ('jackson', '22'), ('jackson', '20'), ('jackson', '24'), ('barkley', '30'), ('barkley', '32'), ('barkley', '33'), ('barkley', '34')]
```

you just iterate over it then iterate over the sublists ... ok no problem :P

Comment: I love list comprehensions! It looks so elite.